# Modify values across all column pyspark

Tags: replace, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements

I have a pyspark data frame and I'd like to have a conditional replacement of a string across multiple columns, not just one. 
To be more concrete: I'd like to replace the string 'HIGH' with 1, and everything else in the column with 0. [Or at least replace every 'HIGH' with 1.] In pandas I would do:

```
df[df == 'HIGH'] = 1
```

Is there a way to do something similar? Or can I do a loop?

I'm new to pyspark so I don't know how to generate example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `replace` method for this:

```
>>> df.replace("HIGH", "1")
```

Keep in mind that you'll need to replace like for like datatypes, so attemping to replace `"HIGH"` with `1` will throw an exception.

Edit:  You could also use `regexp_replace` to address both parts of your question, but you'd need to apply it to all columns:

```
>>> df = df.withColumn("col1", regexp_replace("col1", "^(?!HIGH).*$", "0"))
>>> df = df.withColumn("col1", regexp_replace("col1", "^HIGH$", "1"))
```

Comment: I tried "replace" but it is not working , ex: df.replace("2" , "13")